# Groovy:Invalid duplicate class definition

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm new to Grails/Groovy. I have a Grails project to modify, after importing it in GGTS 3.1.0, I keep getting the following error :

Groovy:Invalid duplicate class definition of class UseUiresourcesPluginConfig : The sources **D:\SVN\Transverse\KAIZEN-trunk\plugins\use-uiresources-plugin-1.0.4\grails-app\conf\UseUiresourcesPluginConfig.groovy** 
and 
**D:\SVN\Transverse\KAIZEN-trunk\grails-app\conf\UseUiresourcesPluginConfig.groovy** are containing both a class of the name UseUiresourcesPluginConfig.

Both files are almost the same, the first contains :

```
resources {

    // What URL patterns should be processed by the resources plugin
    adhoc.patterns = [
        '/images/*',
        '/css/*',
        '/js/*',
        '/plugins/*'
    ]

    mappers {

        // Désactivation de la concaténation des fichiers en mode dev
        bundle.excludes = ['**/*']

        // Désactivation du cache
        hashandcache.excludes = ['**/*']

        // Désactivation de la minification en mode dev
        yuicssminify.disable = true
        googleclosurecompiler.disable = true

        yuicssminify.disable = true     
        // On ne traite pas les fichiers JS (c'est le plugin Google Closure Compiler qui s'en charge)
        yuijsminify.disable = true
    }
}
```

I tried to refresh grails dependencies, to update/clean the project and to reimport it.

Do you have any idea ?

Best regards.

Thomas

Comment: What version of Grails?

Comment: Does it build/run from the command line?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of details. Grails version is 2.2.0. It does build/run from the command line, I'm just worried that this error will cause trouble later.

Comment: Feels like a GGTS issue...  Have you tried a different IDE?

Comment: I tried to import my project on Netbeans, but I don't know anything about this IDE and I'll probably need time to make it work and to become familiar with it. I'd like to learn it but I'm really short in time right now.